# Get the case-insensitive intersection of two lists of strings in Perl

Tags: perl

In Chapter 4, Section 4.8 (Computing Union, Intersection, or Difference of Unique Lists), the [Perl Cookbook](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596003135) provides this technique for getting the intersection of two lists of integers:

```
@a = (1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8);
@b = (2, 3, 5, 7, 9);
...
foreach $e (@a, @b) {
    $union{$e}++ && $isect{$e}++
}
@union = keys %union;
@isect = keys %isect;
```

I want this to be done (case-insensitively) for two lists of strings. Any efficient method, please?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[Array::Utils](http://search.cpan.org/~zmij/Array-Utils-0.5/Utils.pm) is what you're looking for.

```
use Array::Utils qw(:all);

my @a = qw( a b c d );
my @b = qw( c d e f );

my @isect = intersect(@a, @b);
print join(",",@isect) . "\n";
```

This produces the expected output of

```
c,d
```

**Edit:**  I didn't notice that you wanted this done case-insensitively.  In that case, you can replace `@a` with `map{lc}@a` (and likewise with `@b`).

Comment: Just to confirm, the solution(s) provided from cookbook is not suitable for my situation mainly due to the hashing issues of strings, correct?

Comment: Er, actually, no, the solutions in the link you provided work just fine, except for case-sensitivity.  What makes you think they wouldn't?

Comment: @Qiang Li - absolutely not correct. The cookbook uses Perl hashes, which are indexed by strings. In fact, the integers in the example are implicitly converted to strings when they are used as hash keys.

Answer (score 2):

Smallest amount of change required from the original solution. Just lower-case the strings.

```
@a = qw( a b c d );
@b = qw( C D E F );
...
foreach $e (@a, @b) { 
    $union{lc $e}++ && $isect{lc $e}++ 
}

@union = keys %union;
@isect = keys %isect;
```

Comment: Fails on `@a=qw(a b c A B C); @b=();`

Answer (score 2):

Here's one `map`/`grep` approach:

```
my @a = qw(Perl PHP Ruby Python C JavaScript);
my @b = qw(erlang java perl python c snobol lisp);
my @intersection =
    grep { defined }
        @{ { map { lc ,=> $_ } @a } }
           { map { lc } @b };

# @intersection = qw(Perl Python C)
```

Answer (score -1):

You may also use the [duplicates](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::MoreUtils#duplicates-LIST) function from [List::MoreUtils](https://github.com/perl5-utils/List-MoreUtils) module as follows:

```perl
use List::MoreUtils qw( duplicates );

my @php56 = qw( json big_int imap );
my @php44 = qw( json imap bcmath );

say $_
  for duplicates @php56, @php44;

# Output: json, imap
```

This would be equal to the [intersect](https://metacpan.org/release/ZMIJ/Array-Utils-0.5/view/Utils.pm#intersect) of the [Array::Utils](https://metacpan.org/release/ZMIJ/Array-Utils-0.5/view/Utils.pm) module mentioned above.

Answer (score -2):

```
@a = qw(a B c d);
@b = qw(b c D e f);
@c = grep { $f = lc $_; grep lc $_ eq $f, @b } @a;
```

gives

```
B c d
```

1) I found this solution somewhere but I don't remember where. If somebody knows please let me know.

2) I have no idea how efficient this is compared to other solutions.

3) Sincerly, I do not know how this works. Why there is a semicolon and not a comma?