# list the difference and overlap between two data set

Tags: perl

I have two data sets, A and B. The format for each data set is one number per line. For instance,

12345

23456

67891

2345900

12345

Some of the data in A are not included in data set B.  How to list all of these data  in A, and how to list all of those data shared by A and B. Is that possible to do that in Perl?

Comment: almost duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7842114/get-the-intersection-of-two-lists-of-strings-in-perl

Answer (score 5):

This is in the [FAQ](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-do-I-compute-the-difference-of-two-arrays?--How-do-I-compute-the-intersection-of-two-arrays?):

> **How do I compute the difference of two arrays? How do I compute the intersection of two arrays?**
>
> Use a hash. Here's code to do both and more. It assumes that each
>   element is unique in a given array:
>
> ```
> @union = @intersection = @difference = ();
> %count = ();
>
> foreach $element (@array1, @array2) { $count{$element}++ }
>
> foreach $element (keys %count) {
>     push @union, $element;
>     push @{ $count{$element} > 1 ? \@intersection : \@difference }, $element;
> }
> ```
>
> Note that this is the symmetric difference, that is, all elements in
>   either A or in B but not in both. Think of it as an xor operation.

Comment: I added the FAQ as part of the answer.

Comment: Why does code that doesn't compile under `strict` still have its place in the `perldoc`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's called [the intersection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_%28set_theory%29), and there's a module for it: [Set::Intersection](https://metacpan.org/module/Set%3a%3aIntersection). Haven't used it though.

**Edit:** Seems like [Array::Utils](https://metacpan.org/module/Array%3a%3aUtils) has an intersect method as well, I would use that instead.

If you want to program it yourself, you could do something like this:

- put the values into two arrays
- unique them ([List::MoreUtils](https://metacpan.org/module/List%3a%3aMoreUtils) has a uniq())
- use a hash to count how many time you have seen each value
- from the hash, fetch the values count = 2