# Perl - determining the intersection of several numeric ranges

Tags: perl, range, overlap

I would like to be able to load long list of positive integer ranges and create a new "summary" range list that is the union of the intersections of each pairs of ranges. And, I want to do this in Perl. For example:

```
Sample ranges: (1..30) (45..90) (15..34) (92..100)

Intersection of ranges: (15..30)
```

The only way I could think of was using a bunch of nested `if` statements to determine the starting point of sample A, sample B, sample C, etc. and figure out the overlap this way, but it's not possible to do that with hundreds of sample, each containing numerous ranges.

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: Here is an answer that might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7842114/get-the-intersection-of-two-lists-of-strings-in-perl

Comment: That would work great work individual coordinates, but I'm not sure if it is practical for determining the overlapping portions of ranges of coordinates

Comment: The intersection of all ranges here is empty — (45..90) and (92..100) don't intersect with (15..30).

Comment: I meant to say that if at least two or more ranges overlap, the intersecting range would be output, it isn't necessary that all ranges intersect

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first thing you should do when you need to do some thing is take a look at [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/) to see what tools are available of if someone has solved your problem for you already.

[Set::IntSpan](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Set%3a%3aIntSpan) and [Set::IntRange](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Set%3a%3aIntRange) are on the first page of results for "set" on CPAN.

---

What you want is the union of the intersection of each pair of ranges, so the algorithm is as follows:

1. Create an empty result set.
2. Create a set for each range.
3. For each set in the list,

   1. For each later set in the list,

      1. Find the intersection of those two sets.
      2. Find the union of the result set and this intersection. This is the new result set.
4. Enumerate the elements of the result set.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating or posting some example code? I'm new to perl and don't quite see how to implement these tools

Comment: Sure. What are you having a problem with?

Comment: So forgive my inexperience, but tell me if I'm on the right track: I would use $set = new Set::IntSpan @set_specs to create this $set object using an array (stored in @set_specs) of ranges. How should those ranges be formatted for each entry in the array? After that I could use $i_set = intersect $set $set_spec to store all of the intersection in $i_set?

Comment: Ah, you need help finding the algorithm. Added to my answer.

Comment: I follow the logic here, but have a concern: If I have very many lists (let's say 50 instead of just 2), is there a way to do this without using increasingly nested loops?

Comment: If you're trying to find the "intersection" of each pair of list, you'll need to add to levels of loop no matter what. A more efficient algorithm than the I suggested for the inner loops is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have code to share, but I would expand each range into hash, or use a Set module, and then use intersection operations on the sets.